# Is there a way to print a toString from a return statement without overriding a toString method?

Tags: java

Is there a smart and quick way for me to output the string "h" in this code. I'm curious to see if there is some kind of function that can quickly convert the return statement `return h.toString();` to an actual output for me.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Ex1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        a("4 5 1 34 123 1 5 8");

    }
    public static String a(String b) {
        ArrayList<String> c = new ArrayList<>();
        String[] d = b.split (" ");
        int e = 0;
        if(d != null && d.length > 0) {
            for(; e < d.length ; e = e + 1) {
                c.add(0, d[e]);
            }
        }

        Object[] f = c.toArray();
        String[] g = new String[e];
        for(e = 0; e < f.length ; e=e+1) {
            g[e] = f[e].toString();
        }
        String h = "";
        for(String i : g) {
            h = h.toString() + " " + i.toString();
        }
    return h.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: `return Arrays.toString(g);`

Comment: variable h is a String, Is it suppose to be g in your question?

Comment: `return String.join(" ", g);`

Comment: @KarthikJanarthanan Sorry, I accidentally wrote array. I meant the string h.

Comment: Why are you naming your variables with just one letter?

Comment: Like @KarthikJanarthanan `h` is a string.... You just print it straight up. What has your research turned up?

Comment: @WoeIs Turn it into output like: `System.out.println(h);`? (And then optionally making the method void so it doesn't have to return `h`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't mind the json format, Simply use any json lib will do this quick, I believe every json lib has a way to turn a object to json string

like

```
System.out.println(JSONArray.fromObject(myArray).toString());
```